# How can I get ESLint to recognize aggregate export namespaces?

Tags: node.js, eslint

## The Situation

I have a NodeJS project that uses Babel and ESLint (6.8).

I'm using the relatively new syntax for [aggregate exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) (`export * as name1 from …;`).

## The Code

**constants.js**

```
export const x = 5
export const y = 6
```

**index.js**

```
export * as constants from './constants'
```

**sandbox.js**

```
import { constants } from './index'
console.log(constants.x)
```

When I run `babel-node sandbox.js` everything works just fine, and the value for `x` (`5`) is rendered.

**.eslintrc**

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb-base",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "13.10"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from"
  ]
}
```

### The Problem

ESLint seems to be confused by my aggregate export, rendering the following error when I lint:

```
sandbox.js
  1:10  error  constants not found in './index'  import/named
```

### The Question

How do I get ESLint to recognize that the named aggregate does in fact exist?  I would like to be able to still benefit from the `import/named` checks overall.

Comment: I suspect this might be a bug within the eslint import plugin itself, and so I opened a ticket: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1753

Comment: ESLint 7 recognizes aggregate export statements out of the box (without babel-eslint).

Comment: Ah thank you -- I should specify the version of eslint in my question.  And this is very good to know, will look into upgrading.

Comment: If you upgrade, be sure to include `"parserOptions": { "ecmaVersion": 2020, "sourceType": "module" }` in your `.eslintrc`.